# MVC Pattern: Does The View should has reference to The Model

Tags: model-view-controller, design-patterns

In MVC Pattern: when user types something, Control will "translate" user input to Model to process data.

But, in other scene, for example my form has a list box and load data from database when it's loading.
So, the loading method I should put in The View or I should call this through Control.

For example:
View:

```
public void Loading(){
   //some init here
   //load data from database
}
public void Loading(){
   //some init here
   //control.loadDatabase();
}
```

Which is the best in this pattern. Please give me an advice.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The relationship between the model and the view is described by a design pattern, called [Observer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern), whereby the model is the subject, and the view an observer.
That means that the model notifies the view, when there is new data available.

Comment: Yes. But in my case, when loading data, nothing change in model. so, which part I should put loadDatabase() into ? View, Control or Model ?

Answer (score 0):

The list box is part of the view so you should load it with the controller! In mvc the view doesn't t know nothing about model.so you can change the model without changing the view and vice versa.